# Adding an additional row that spans in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to have an additional row due to room issues.  I have data coming in on a row, but I'd like to have a second row that provides additional data like so:

```
row 1  |Field 1|Field 2|Field 3|
row 1.5|Additional information |
row 2  |Field 1|Field 2|Field 3|
row 2.5|Additional information |
```

Where row .5 is the row i'd like to insert.  Is there a way to do with out creating an additional row on row create?  Or is there a way to do this all within the same row?

thanks!

Comment: Are you bound to a grid view? This can be easily done with repeater. Also just found [this](http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm), but have never used it

Comment: I guess I am not bound to a repeater, but it would take a little more re factoring than I i'd like to do if there is a solution to work with the existing Gridview.

Comment: @Andrei after looking into it, the reason why I am using the gridview is to have access to all of the functionality of edit itemtemplates and add items.

Comment: You can use a repeater... just need to code in edit templates etc... take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247289/In-place-editing-with-ASP-NET-Repeater

Comment: @Mych if you'd like to submit that as an answer, it's the route I went.

Comment: @Herrozerro I've done that although all I did was a search on something I had used in the past. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridviews have built in built in Edit/Delete commands but can be restrictive as far as layout is concerned. Using a Repeater can give you the layout you desire but you will need to code in Add/Edit/Delete methods as required. A good tutorial can be found here... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/247289/In-place-editing-with-ASP-NET-Repeater

I know that providing a link as an answer is not desirable as articles can dissapear but it is a long article...

Answer (score 0):

I recently added rows like that inside a GridView, following the example in this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20047/Editable-Nested-GridView-All-in-One

He put another gridview inside the new row, but you can add something else if you prefer. Here is one of the key points from the article:

> ...we must understand how GridView emits its content as HTML tags. For
>   an Internet Explorer browser, GridView is like a regular Table with TR
>   and TD tags. So, if we can manipulate the parent GridView to forcibly
>   close a row and emit a child GridView as another row, we are done with
>   it.
>
> What is displayed is some HTML table cell and row tags that
>   effectively intercept the current output that will be generated by the
>   GridView with our own special implementation. Namely, we are telling
>   the table (when it's drawn) to close the current cell, the current
>   row, and now add a new row with one blank column (for spacing) and
>   another column (spanning all columns) that we'll use to display second
>   GridView.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" ">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">
                <div id="div<%# Eval("Material_Selected_ID")%>" style="position: relative; left: 280px; overflow: auto; width: 97%">
                    <!-- Your new line of data goes here. In my case I added a user control that referenced the current line of data. -->
                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```